Insert Statement w/ sub-query that has multiple records
How can use a sub-query with an insert statement?
Example:
INSERT INTO SCHOOLCARD (SchoolCardID, ScheduleID, Course1, Course2, Course3, ScheduleNote)
VALUES (LOWER(NEWID()),
        (SELECT ScheduleID FROM SCHEDULES 
         WHERE SCHEDULESID = 'Spring 24'),
        'Math A', 'Science B', 'Art A', 'Final Grades')


Why should I "tag my RDBMS"? - please add a tag to specify whether you're using mysql, postgresql, sql-server, oracle or db2 - or something else entirely.

even tagged, where cpme the other column from?  from air?
